# Flutter Navigation - How do you set up file pages in index?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I would like to use different dart files/scripts to show the pages when clicking on the navigation bar. The error is within the final screen section where I have set different pages to be loaded. However methods can't be found and I would like to ask how do I make this appear and all work together?

I have been following this tutorial and he skips what to do when linking up files within the navigation bar.

This is the youtube video I am following: (goto 6:44)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoKqQjSDZ60

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    HomePage(),
    BuisnessPage(),
    SchoolPage(),
    SettingsPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bottom Navigation Bar'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        iconSize: 30,
        //selectedFontSize: 16,
        //unselectedFontSize: 14,
        //showUnselectedLabels: false,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
            backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**buisnesspage.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BuisnessPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuisnessPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Test B'),
    ),
    body: Center(child: Text('Test B', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60))),
  );
}
```

**Error:**

> lib/main.dart:29:5: Error: Method not found: 'HomePage'.
> HomePage(),
> ^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:30:5: Error: Method not found: 'BuisnessPage'.
> BuisnessPage(),
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:31:5: Error: Method not found: 'SchoolPage'.
> SchoolPage(),
> ^^^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:32:5: Error: Method not found: 'SettingsPage'.
> SettingsPage(),
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I don't get any issue with your code in the dartpad run and it would be good to share your final screen code, most probably you made mistake in the final screen.

Comment: I will place the error at the bottom of the page, can you review that? Do I need a package to link the pages together? Do I need to make classes within the main.dart to make it work?

Comment: Check out this and let me know https://gist.github.com/Jahidul007/74520ea23873ba6f5de63cce93064574#file-navigation-dart

Comment: It works but I wanted to pull code from different pages (files) within the lib.

Comment: just create this separate class and pull them

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you did not import the classes used in `main.dart`
try to :

```
import 'pathtoyour/HomePage.dart';
import 'pathtoyour/BuisnessPage.dart';
import 'pathtoyour/SchoolPage.dart';
import 'pathtoyour/SettingsPage.dart';
```

and also try to type your variables to avoid errors that are difficult to understand,

```
final List<Widget> screens = const [
    HomePage(),
    BuisnessPage(),
    SchoolPage(),
    SettingsPage(),
  ];
```

if it's ok, give me a feedback

or at least try to specify what your list contains :

```
final screens = <Widget>[
    HomePage(),
    BuisnessPage(),
    SchoolPage(),
    SettingsPage(),
  ];
```